# okhttp post request sending null values to server

Tags: php, android, okhttp

I'm developing simple android application that making simple post request to server. But it sending null values for both keys which are required as request body from server. I've check it from my app end but it's not sending null values.

here's my php code.

```
<?php
include 'DBConnection.php';

$db = DBConnection::getInstance ();
$db = DBConnection::getInstance ();
$mysqli = $db->getConnection ();

$username = $_POST ['username'];
$password = $_POST ['password'];

$result_array = array (
    "username " => $username,
    "password " => $password
);

echo (json_encode($result_array));
?>
```

Here's the code in my android application.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new LoginPostRequest().execute(RestConnection.LOGIN_POST);
            }
        });
    }

private class LoginPostRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Object, String> {

        private  RequestBody body;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            String userNameData = userName.getText().toString().replace(" ","");
            String PasswordData = password.getText().toString().replace(" ","");
            JSONObject requestBody = new JSONObject();

            try {
                requestBody.put("username", userNameData);
                requestBody.put("password", PasswordData);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Login onPreExecute"+e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

            String string = requestBody.toString();
            body = RequestBody.create(JSON, string);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String urlEndPoint = params[0];

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(RestConnection.API_BASE+urlEndPoint)
                    .post(body)
                    .build();

            try {
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                return response.body().string();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "String";

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            JSONObject responseBody;
            try {
                responseBody = new JSONObject(response);
                String message = responseBody.getString("message");

                if(!message.equals("login failed")){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainMenuActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Login onPostExecute :"+e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

        }
    }
```

I'm using okhttp version v3.5.0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: would recommend using `Retrofit`/`gson` when interacting with REST API.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32856401/using-okhttp-library-for-posting-to-a-php-script-that-saves-to-mysql it has a complete example..

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 It's the old version on okhttp. not the answer I'm looking for. Point out any errors in my code i'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34826520/how-to-send-post-parameters-dynamically-or-in-loop-in-okhttp-3-x-in-android?rq=1). Need to use `FormBody.Builder`. For some reason it's not work the way it says on okhttp site. (the way I tried in my question).

here's my edited AsyncTask class.

```
private class LoginPostRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Object, String> {

        private  RequestBody body;
        private HashMap<String,String> postData;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            String userNameData = userName.getText().toString().replace(" ","");
            String PasswordData = password.getText().toString().replace(" ","");

            postData = new HashMap<>();
            postData.put("username",userNameData);
            postData.put("password",PasswordData);

            FormBody.Builder builder = new FormBody.Builder();

            for ( Map.Entry<String, String> entry : postData.entrySet() ) {
                builder.add( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() );
            }

            body = builder.build();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String urlEndPoint = params[0];

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(RestConnection.API_BASE+urlEndPoint)
                    .post(body)
                    .build();
            try {
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                return response.body().string();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {

            JSONObject responseBody;
            try {
                responseBody = new JSONObject(response);
                String message = responseBody.getString("message");

                if(!message.equals("login failed")){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainMenuActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Login onPostExecute :"+e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

        }
    }
```